# MUI textfield label not floating to the top left properly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I try to use the MUI in my project, and all the input fields I use don't behave correctly.

it supposed to look like this
[image: image from MUI website]

but when I use it it will look like this

[image]

```
import Box from '@mui/material/Box'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField'
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete'

<Autocomplete
className="mt-3"
size="small"
id="country-select-demo"
options={arr}
autoHighlight
getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
renderOption={(props, option) => (
<Box
component="li"
sx={{ '& > img': { mr: 2, flexShrink: 0 } }}
{...props}
>
{option.label}
</Box>
)}
renderInput={(params) => (
<TextField
{...params}
label="Choose.."
inputProps={{
...params.inputProps,
}}
/>
)}
```

Comment: Could you provide the mt-3 class style that you setting?

Comment: I just realize that I just need to uninstall my react-bootstrap in order for MUI to function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that uninstalling the react-bootstrap fix this problem.